# How to filter a model by using child model's field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hava a `Company` class that `has_many` `TerminalValue`. And the `TerminalValue` has a field `forecast.

I want to filter companies that have at least a `TerminalValue` those `forecast` is `true`.

I tried like this, but failed.

```
 Company.where(terminal_values: {forecast: true})
  Company Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "terminal_values"."forecast" = 't'
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "terminal_values"
LINE 1: SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "terminal_values...
                                                    ^
: SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "terminal_values"."forecast" = 't'
```

How can I write the filtering method that I want?

Comment: Try `Company.includes(:terminal_values).where('terminal_values.forecast = ?', true).references(:terminal_values)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use either `joins` or `includes` to achieve what you want.

***joins***

```
Company.joins(:terminal_values).where('terminal_values.forecast = ?', true)
```

***includes***

```
Company.includes(:terminal_values).where('terminal_values.forecast = ?', true).references(:terminal_values)
```